# Regex in javascript doesn't work when passed as a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this Regex :-

```
let rgb = new RegExp(/rgb\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*\)/);
```

Now, this is working just fine on "rgb( 255 , 0, 255 )"

But I need to write and test this in VS Code,
Node.js gives syntax errors when I pass the regex like this, so I'm passing it as a string :

```
let rgb = new RegExp("rgb\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*\)");
```

But this regex isn't validating my string.
Need help to use this regex in Node.js

Comment: What is it not validating? May you show some examples of that?

Comment: ex: rgb( 255, 15 , 255). My issue is that browser is accepting this regex as parameter in 
new RegExp(/rgb\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*\)/) but node.js gives syntax errors. why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the regex like this

```
let rgb = /rgb\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*\)/
```

Then test it like this

```
rgb.exec(string_to_test_against);
```

Read more about js regex here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: this method works. no syntax error when I do it like this in node.js :- 

let regex = /rgb\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*\)/;
let newRegEx = new RegExp(regex);
console.log("test " + newRegEx.test("rgb( 255 , 15 , 120 )"));